# Will rapid screen refresh hurt its life?

Tags: display, external-display

I sometimes use a script I wrote to invert my screen's colors as fast as the screen will refresh to make it like a strobe light for raves. Will changing the colors on my monitor this fast take way from the monitor's life more than just having it on?

Comment: +1 for creativity on using your monitor "to make it like a strobe light for raves"

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that it's a LCD monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a LCD monitor, your monitor life depends on two main things: **brightness and contrast** combined with turned-on time. If you are using it as a "strobe light for raves" I assume that you are using it's brightness and contrast at the max, so the answear is **Yes, it is reducing your monitor lifetime** not just because these two main reasons, but due to the fact that you are changing collors very quickly(for fullscreen). LCD monitors are primary projected to be used with workstations, where the collors of screen don't change very quickly along a normal work day as you are doing. Also, each collor change depends on a re-polarization of the layer before the LCD backlight, which depends of a eletrical stimulus, what will naturally degradate the colors receptors over time.

Additionally, [here](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/) you can test your monitor collors:

> Welcome to the Lagom LCD monitor test pages. With the test images on
>   these pages, you can easily adjust the settings of your monitor to get
>   the best possible picture quality. Additionally, there are a number of
>   test images that can help you to judge the image quality of a monitor.
>   You can check the images on this webpage or put them on a usb stick
>   and try them in the computer store like I did when I created these
>   test patterns. These test images are much more revealing regarding
>   monitor shortcomings than ordinary photographs.
>
> I'm offering these pages for free. In return, I just ask you to
>   respect my copyright. Do not place these images on other websites or
>   web forums, and don't link directly to the images.